# Nested if statment, json, django

Tags: python, json, django, if-statement

My code which is working:

```
 def json_response(self, request): 
      ...

        return JsonResponse({
'Name': 'Harry' if name.pretty else name.something
```

I want to add nested if statment but i dont know how. It should be something like:

'Name': Harry if name.pretty else name.something(if exists) otherwise name.something_else

Comment: supposing we test for a and b: `{'Name': 'Harry' if a else 'Barry' if b else 'Larry'}`. Although I would say that this is little bit unreadable and you should simply construct your dictionary and have if-else etc. in separate lines instead of writing a one-liner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should look like this

```py
{
    "Name": "Harry" if name.pretty else name.something if YOUR_CONDITION else name.something_else
}
```

> You can nest your [ternary operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-operator-in-python/#highlighter_869130:%7E:text=Ternary%20operator%20can%20be%20written%20as%20nested%20if%2Delse%3A) as much as you can